# Makefiles: What is an order-only prerequisite?

Tags: makefile

The GNU make manual introduces [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html):

```
target: prerequisite1 prerequisite2 | orderonlyprerequisite1 orderonlyprerequisite2
```

However, while that manual page gives an example and describes the purpose of order-only prerequisites, at no point does the manual page answer the question in the title: **What is an order-only prerequisite?**

Can you give a precise definition how order-only prerequisites behave?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First, let's recall what the ordinary prerequisites are.

Basically, the prerequisites in Makefile have two functions:

1. They are checked and, if necessary, are built *before* the target
2. If any of the prerequisites gets rebuilt (or is simply newer than the target) then the target will also be rebuilt.

Now, the *order-only* prerequisites do item 1, i.e. impose build-order, but not item 2.

Comment: This doesn't explain which run first the ordered prerequisites or the normal ones.  For example, are the normal ones supposed to complete first, before the ordered ones are ran?  I'm seeing them all essentially be parallelized when I have two on the right and one of them itself is parallelized, but the docs don't say anything about that.

Comment: @TrentonD.Adams Parallel execution is a different question which, I believe, was answered many times before.

Comment: @TrentonD.Adams You cannot suppose that. All prerequisites will follow same rules, and the normal ones won't necesarily be completed before the order-only ones. For GNU Make targets, all its children are the same, although the order-only prerequisites won't force a target rebuilt by themselves.

Answer (score 49):

Suppose you have a Makefile like this

```
baby: love
    touch $@

love: 
    touch $@
```

then `make` says,

```
touch love
touch baby
```

now you `rm love` and again `make` say

```
touch love
touch baby
```

because in order to make baby you must make love, *and* every time you make love, you must make baby.  However, suppose you don't want to make baby every time you make love. In that case you can use a pipe.

```
baby: | love
    touch $@
```

now you `rm love` and `make` says only

```
touch love
```

because although in order to make baby you must make love, it is *not* the case that every time you make love, you must make baby.

Comment: In other words the target is not executed on prerequisite update. But I'm wondering about one thing, all this seems to work only if creation of files/folders is involved in recipes (`touch` in your example), but what if recipe is a command not related to creating/updating any file or folder? How to guarantee that order-only prerequisite does not enforce target?

Comment: For instance, I replaced `touch` in your example with `echo` and now both target and prerequisite are always executed, no matter if I use order-only or not. Does it mean, the target should always have `touch` to make sure that it's already been executed and hence does not need to be executed again?

Comment: Oh, moreover, looks like the filename should be exactly the same as the target name, other filenames won't work (I guess this is why `$@` is used)

Comment: @mangusta the `make` is intended to do incremental build. if something is not out of date, then it won't be rebuilt. The only way `make` can know if something is out of date is my looking at the date of the **file**.  So yes, the target must match the filename. However, if you want to use echo instead of touch, then you need to use phony targets. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html

Comment: I cannot resist commenting on this brilliant metaphor in the used example! Lol

Comment: This is should be the top acceptable answer. Now I will never forget what an order only prerequisite is.

Comment: I never seen anything like this before in stackoverflow lol. This guy is a genius.

Comment: "because in order to make baby you must make love, and every time you make love, you must make baby" -- but if you wanted to do that, couldn't you just run 'make love'? That would already make love without making baby. If you're running 'make baby', doesn't that mean you want to make baby too?

Comment: I think I understand the use-case now, it's for prerequisites which must be present but whose content does not affect the outcome of the target produced. In the example: producing baby requires love, but changing love won't affect what baby will be produced. So we don't need to bother reproducing baby, and so only produce love.

Comment: @mherzl yes that is a good way to think of it.  Also, without any pipe, `love` is a prerequisite *resource* of `baby`.  But with a pipe, `love` is a prerequisite *action* of `baby`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the documentation does describe how they behave.  It describes how a normal prerequisite behaves:

> A normal prerequisite makes two statements: first, it imposes an order in which recipes will be invoked: the recipes for all prerequisites of a target will be completed before the recipe for the target is run. Second, it imposes a dependency relationship: if any prerequisite is newer than the target, then the target is considered out-of-date and must be rebuilt.

Then it describes how the behavior of an order-only prerequisite differs from that; it will:

> impose a specific ordering on the rules to be invoked *without* forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already quoted the GNU make manual and given example Makefiles. I'd like to add two situations that benefit from order-only prerequisites.

First, **directories as targets.** You want to create a file `bin/package.jar`, and you want to create `bin` if necessary. This Makefile fragment looks good:

```
bin/package.jar: bin
    jar cfm $@ manifest.txt $(CLASSES)

bin:
    mkdir $@
```

But it has a potential flaw. If `bin` is ever newer than `bin/package.jar`, then make will rebuild `bin/package.jar` when it doesn't need to. Yet `bin`'s modification time changes if any files change inside it! This can happen for unexpected reasons in larger Makefiles. The manual describes this:

> In this situation, you want the directory to be created before any
> targets are placed into it but, because the timestamps on directories
> change whenever a file is added, removed, or renamed, we certainly
> don’t want to rebuild all the targets whenever the directory’s
> timestamp changes. One way to manage this is with order-only
> prerequisites: make the directory an order-only prerequisite on all
> the targets:

```
bin/package.jar: | bin
    jar cfm $@ manifest.txt $(CLASSES)

bin:
    mkdir $@
```

Second, **checking if a file exists but ignoring its contents.** Suppose you want the same Makefile to create `manifest.txt`, checking for a Java source file and putting its name inside `manifest.txt`. Again, use an order-only prerequisite:

```
MAINCLASS=Coffee

manifest.txt: | $(MAINCLASS).java
    echo "Main-Class: $(MAINCLASS)" > $@

# Other targets may use $(MAINCLASS).java or $(MAINCLASS).class
```

`manifest.txt` requires `$(MAINCLASS).java` to exist. But changing the contents of `$(MAINCLASS).java` (which changes its modification time, which is what make uses) should not rebuild `manifest.txt`.