# Difference between order_only prerequisites and non-order_only prerequisites in rake

Tags: ruby, rake

Rake has added an `order_only` feature in [13.0](https://github.com/ruby/rake/commit/5e6c6f474d224721308cba5e82162113c849b5e3), which is probably based on GNU Make's [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html).

Information on how order-only prerequisites should work is further clarified in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039810/makefiles-what-is-an-order-only-prerequisite).

The problem however is I don't see how it actually works in rake.  Like for example if I run `rake install` and then I run `rake build`, `rake install` doesn't run again when `build` is not an order only prerequisite of it.  Maybe I'm just misinformed, or maybe some other factors like timestamps and how the `needed?` method affect how it behaves, but I'm a little tired to further examine the source code of rake.

In the merge commit, order only prerequisites seem only assigned differently from `prerequisites`, and nothing else is demonstrated.

Anyway I hope someone can elaborately describe how `order_only` should work in rake with completeness; showing examples and citing source code of rake if possible.  This will greatly help me and other Rakefile writers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like someone added this so that you could build some order_only commands in Rake, but didn't add support for this to the built-in file commands. It does store the order_only prerequisites in a separate member variable in the task, so you can make your own version of the FileTask that will work like the GNU Make's order-only prerequisites. Here's an example Rakefile:

```rb
class OrderOnlyFileTask < Rake::FileTask
  def out_of_date?(stamp)
    all_regular_prerequisite_tasks.any? { |prereq|
      prereq_task = application[prereq, @scope]
      if prereq_task.instance_of?(Rake::FileTask)
        prereq_task.timestamp > stamp || @application.options.build_all
      else
        prereq_task.timestamp > stamp
      end
    }
  end
  
  def all_regular_prerequisite_tasks
    seen = {}
    collect_regular_prerequisites(seen)
    seen.values
  end
  
  def collect_regular_prerequisites(seen)
    regular_prerequisite_tasks.each do |pre|
      next if seen[pre.name]
      seen[pre.name] = pre
      pre.collect_prerequisites(seen)
    end
  end
  
  def regular_prerequisite_tasks
    prerequisites.map { |pre| lookup_prerequisite(pre) }
  end
end   

file 'foo/created.txt' do
  mkdir 'foo'
  touch 'foo/created.txt'
end

file 'source.txt' do
  touch 'source.txt'
end

OrderOnlyFileTask.define_task('foo/built.txt' => ['source.txt'], order_only: ['foo/created.txt']) do
  touch 'foo/built.txt'
end

task :build => 'foo/built.txt' do
  puts 'build'
end
```

If I start from scratch and run `rake build` I get this output:

```sh
% rake build
touch source.txt
mkdir foo
touch foo/created.txt
touch foo/built.txt
build
```

If I run it again:

```sh
% rake build
build
```

If I update the mtime on foo/created.txt:

```sh
% touch foo/created.txt
% rake build
build
```

If I modify the source file:

```sh
% touch source.txt
% rake build
touch foo/built.txt
build
```

If I delete the foo directory:

```sh
% rm -rf foo
% rake build
mkdir foo
touch foo/created.txt
touch foo/built.txt
build
```

If you change the `OrderOnlyFileTask` to have a regular prerequisite for foo/created.txt like this:

```rb
OrderOnlyFileTask.define_task('foo/built.txt' => ['source.txt', 'foo/created.txt']) do
  touch 'foo/built.txt'
end
```

Then you get different behavior when foo/created.txt is touched:

```sh
% touch foo/created.txt
% rake build
touch foo/built.txt
build
```

I made the dependency here a file (foo/created.txt) instead of a directory like in the GNU Make example because the directory task in Rake doesn't check the mtime of the directory like directory dependencies in make.

So with the order_only option to a task you can build your own Rake tasks that treat the order_only prerequisites differently when deciding whether to execute or not. You just need to define `needed?` in your task to handle prerequisites how you want. All those methods I put in OrderOnlyFileTask are to change the `needed?` method in FileTask to ignore the order_only prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, `rake` already has order-only tasks. They are [`directory`](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v13.0.6/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb#L93-L101) (or [`file_create`](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v13.0.6/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb#L83) for that matter) tasks ([link](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v13.0.6/lib/rake/file_creation_task.rb)):

> A FileCreationTask is a file task that when used as a dependency will be needed if and only if the file has not been created.  Once created, it is not re-triggered if any of its dependencies are newer, nor does trigger any rebuilds of tasks that depend on it whenever it is updated.

But that is owing to the fact that that their timestamps are [always less](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v13.0.6/lib/rake/file_creation_task.rb#L21) than that of any other task. Not because other tasks can ignore it (not because the timestamp of a `directory`/`file_create` task is ignored when it's an order-only dependency).

```
directory 'build'
file 'build/a' => ['a.c', 'build'] do
  system('gcc a.c -o build/a', exception: true)
end
```

```
$ rake -t build/a
** Invoke build/a (first_time)
** Invoke a.c (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build (first_time)
** Execute build
mkdir -p build
** Execute build/a

$ touch build
$ rake -t build/a
** Invoke build/a (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke a.c (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build (first_time, not_needed)
```

```
file_create 'b' do
  touch 'b'
end
file 'a' => ['a.c', 'b'] do
  system('gcc a.c -o a', exception: true)
end
```

```
$ rake -t a
** Invoke a (first_time)
** Invoke a.c (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke b (first_time)
** Execute b
touch b
** Execute a

$ touch b
$ rake -t a
** Invoke a (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke a.c (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke b (first_time, not_needed)
```

Peter Haight's `OrderOnlyFileTask` class proves that order-only dependencies can be treated specially (although only immediate dependencies of the class are treated this way, which is okay, since that is apparently a proof-of-concept). It seems like the feature hasn't been released yet, or that it's part of some sort of private API.